# Elasticseach not using synonyms from synonym file

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to elasticsearch so before downvoting or marking as duplicate, please read the question first.

I am testing synonyms in elasticsearch (v 2.4.6) which I have installed on Ubuntu 16.04. I am giving synonyms through a file named **synonym.txt** which I have placed in **config** directory. I have created an index **synonym_test** as follows-

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/synonym_test/ -d '{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_synonyms": {
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
            "filter": ["lowercase","my_synonym_filter"] 
            }
         },
      "filter": {
        "my_synonym_filter": {
          "type": "synonym", 
            "ignore_case": true,
              "synonyms_path" : "synonym.txt"
              }
          }
      }
   }
}'
```

The index contains two fields- **id** and **some_text**. I configure the field **some_text** with the custom analyzer as follows-

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/synonym_test/rulers/_mapping -d '{
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "double"
      },
    "some_text": {
      "type": "string",
          "search_analyzer": "my_synonyms"       
          }
      }
 }'
```

Then I have inserted some data as -

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/synonym_test/external/5 -d '{
  "id" : "5",
  "some_text":"apple is a fruit"
}'
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/synonym_test/external/7 -d '{
  "id" : "7",
  "some_text":"english is spoken in england"
}'
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/synonym_test/external/8 -d '{
  "id" : "8",
  "some_text":"Scotland Yard is a popular game."
}'
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/synonym_test/external/9 -d '{
  "id" : "9",
  "some_text":"bananas contain potassium"
}'
```

The synonym.txt file contains following-

```
"britain,england,scotland"
"fruit,bananas"
```

After doing all this, when I run the query for term **fruit** (which should also return the text containing bananas as they are synonyms in file), I get the text containing fruit only.

```json
{
  "took":117,
   "timed_out":false,
   "_shards":{  
      "total":5,
      "successful":5,
      "failed":0
   },
   "hits":{  
      "total":1,
      "max_score":0.8465736,
      "hits":[  
         {  
            "_index":"synonym_test",
            "_type":"external",
            "_id":"5",
            "_score":0.8465736,
            "_source":{  
               "id":"5",
               "some_text":"apple is a fruit"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I have also tried the following links, but none seem to have helped me -
[Synonym analyzer not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39148225/synonym-analyzer-not-working) ,
[Elasticsearch synonym analyzer not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29354312/elasticsearch-synonym-analyzer-not-working) , [How to apply synonyms at query time instead of index time in Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42071623/how-to-apply-synonyms-at-query-time-instead-of-index-time-in-elasticsearch) , [how to configure the synonyms_path in elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405779/how-to-configure-the-synonyms-path-in-elasticsearch) and many other links.

So, can anyone please tell me if I am doing anything wrong? Is there anything wrong with the settings or synonym file? I want the synonyms to work **(query time)** so that when I search for a term, I get all documents related to that term.

Comment: did you try writing synonyms without `"` just like `britain,england,scotland` ?

Comment: @RaheelKhan Yes, I tried both ways.

Comment: are you using englihs stemmer ?

Comment: it will be helpful if you post your mapping also

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to following url: [Custom Analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-custom-analyzer.htm) on how you should configure custom analyzers.
If we follow the guides from above documentation our schema will be as follows:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/synonym_test/ -d '{
  "settings": {
"analysis": {
  "analyzer": {
    "type": "custom"
    "my_synonyms": {
      "tokenizer": "whitespace",
        "filter": ["lowercase","my_synonym_filter"] 
        }
     },
  "filter": {
    "my_synonym_filter": {
      "type": "synonym", 
        "ignore_case": true,
          "synonyms_path" : "synonym.txt"
          }
      }
  }
  }
}
```

Which currently works on my elasticsearch instance.